# Setting up Proguard with a Library project that depends on external jars

Tags: android, proguard, showcaseview

My android project has many dependencies, one of them has a libs folder with some jars, and everything is working fine until i try using proguard.

When running proguard i got an error with this log:

```
Warning: [!!few lines like this!!]: can't find superclass or interface [...]
Warning: [!!many lines like this!!]: can't find referenced class [...]
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 190 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile them and try again.
         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

then i tried to add the -libraryjars flag in my proguard config file, resulting in this additional warning, above the others:

```
Note: there were 698 duplicate class definitions.
```

The library project i cannot proguard is ShowcaseView (com.espian.showcaseview).

The jars in its library's libs folder are:

- android-support-v4.jar
- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
- nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar

What should i do?!

**EDIT**

here's my proguard.cfg

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

#-libraryjars ../ShowcaseView-master/library/libs/android-support-v4.jar
#-libraryjars ../ShowcaseView-master/library/libs/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
#-libraryjars ../ShowcaseView-master/library/libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}


#this is a try for all assets and res/raw/*html!
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class **.R$*


#ACRA specifics
# Restore some Source file names and restore approximate line numbers in the stack traces,
# otherwise the stack traces are pretty useless
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
# Note: This may already be defined in the default "proguard-android-optimize.txt"
# file in the SDK. If it is, then you don't need to duplicate it. See your
# "project.properties" file to get the path to the default "proguard-android-optimize.txt".
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Comment: I added my complete proguard.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-libraryjars /libs/mail.jar
-libraryjars /libs/activation.jar
-libraryjars /libs/additionnal.jar
```

Write your jar file path into the progurd.cfg or proguard-project.txt

Comment: As i wrote in my question, i tried to add -libraryjars but with the only result to obtain a new warning: Note: there were 698 duplicate class definitions. so, i don't think that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these lines for your libraries. They will don't warn for **can't find reference class**

> -keep class com.nineoldandroids.** { *; }
>
> -dontwarn  -com.nineoldandroids.**